# Shopify - How do I prevent product variants dropdown menus from loading?

Tags: product, shopify

Whenever I reload/load my products page, the dropdown product variants menus take a tiny fraction of time to load when the whole page is already loaded. They're just completely gone, then show up after a bit.

I would have no issues with this if the entire content of what's below them didn't pan up while they were loading, like the cart button. Content with the :absolute function will start overlaping.

I find this odd because when I apply this guide here: (http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/showcasing-products/add-color-swatches-to-your-products) the loading is gone!

I've also noticed that one or two themes don't have this issue.

PLEASE help. I'm using the minimal theme and you can see the effects of what I'm talking about on the demo page itself: http://minimal-fashion.myshopify.com/collections/frontpage/products/inkjet-halter-dress

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of the parent container: `<div class="selector-wrapper">`

HTML:

```
<div id="variant-container" class="selector-wrapper">
```

CSS:

```
#variant-container {
  height: 68px;
}
```